# Publish to only the ticker?

Tags: facebook, ticker

Is it possible to publish to only the ticker using JS, and not have a story also in the main page panel?

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is: Yes, it is possible using new features of Facebook OpenGraph (beta).

It may be / or not something you understand by word publish:
What is published to the ticker is actions (and I remember correct game achievements).

According to [new Facebook OpenGraph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/):

> When an action is published, the activity may appear in their News
>   Feed and friends' News Feeds and will appear in their friends' Ticker.

You can read more about [actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/#actions-objects) and [actions publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/#publish)

Not sure if Facebook's meaning of words *may* and *will* is the same as in English.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The issue I'm seeing though, is if I use something to the effect of:     `FB.api('/me/_namespace:read?article=http://someurl.com','post',...` It's showing in the ticker AND the wall.  Must this always be the case?  And if not, how can it be done?  Thanks!